# Why can't I aggregate with MongoDB with a $match?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My code is:

```
db.essays.aggregate({
  $match: {
    essayId: 3
  },
  $group: {
    _id: {
      year: {
        $year: '$essayTime'
      },
      month: {
        $month: '$essayTime'
      },
      day: {
        $dayOfMonth: '$essayTime'
      }
    },
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
});
```

It returns an error: `"exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field."`

However, if I do it without the `$match`, then it returns as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put each pipeline stage into its own object within an array:

```js
db.essays.aggregate([
  { $match: {
    essayId: 3
  }},
  { $group: {
    _id: {
      year: {
        $year: '$essayTime'
      },
      month: {
        $month: '$essayTime'
      },
      day: {
        $dayOfMonth: '$essayTime'
      }
    },
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }}
]);
```